# how to push new values to existing array in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have group document within the document I have members. Every group have unique groupId and I want to add new members to groups based on the groupId

**group table**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6011208469d905d40038ddc5"),
"groupId: ObjectId("5fd484439590020dc0dfb829"),
"name" : "Fun Friends",
"members" : [ 
        {
            "isdCode" : "001",
            "phone" : "11"
        }, 
        {
            "isdCode" : "001",
            "phone" : "12"
        }
    ]
}
```

exepected output

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6011208469d905d40038ddc5"),
"groupId: ObjectId("5fd484439590020dc0dfb829"),
"name" : "Fun Friends",
"members" : [ 
        {
            "isdCode" : "001",
            "phone" : "11"
        }, 
        {
            "isdCode" : "001",
            "phone" : "12"
        },
        {
            "isdCode" : "001",
            "phone" : "13"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you read the documentation ?

Comment: yes, but lot of confusion which to use.

Comment: Thanks you very much , It's Working fine